# How to reform this dataframe to be longer?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here I have a table (it is really large, I just give a simplified example)

```
import pandas as pd

indices = (1,2,3,4)
columns = ["id", "height1", "height2", "height3"]
data = (["xxx1", 1, 2, 3], ["xxx2", 4, 5, 6], ["xxx3", 7, 8, 9], ["xxx4", 10, 11, 12])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = indices, columns = columns)
df
```

which returns
[image]

However, what should I do if I want to this dataframe to be displayed in this way?
I tried to use groupby(id) and then unstack() but failed.

Any help or hint is welcome

```
 id   height  score
xxx1  height1    1
xxx1  height2    2
xxx1  height3    3
xxx2  height1    4
xxx2  height2    5
.
.
.
xxx4  height3   12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
In [99]: df
Out[99]:
     id  height1  height2  height3
1  xxx1        1        2        3
2  xxx2        4        5        6
3  xxx3        7        8        9
4  xxx4       10       11       12

In [100]: df.set_index('id').stack().reset_index().set_axis(['id', 'height', 'score'], axis=1)
Out[100]:
      id   height  score
0   xxx1  height1      1
1   xxx1  height2      2
2   xxx1  height3      3
3   xxx2  height1      4
4   xxx2  height2      5
5   xxx2  height3      6
6   xxx3  height1      7
7   xxx3  height2      8
8   xxx3  height3      9
9   xxx4  height1     10
10  xxx4  height2     11
11  xxx4  height3     12
```

the main stuff is `df.set_index('id').stack()`
docs: [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

Answer (score 3):

Let us try just `melt`

```
df.melt('id')
      id variable  value
0   xxx1  height1      1
1   xxx2  height1      4
2   xxx3  height1      7
3   xxx4  height1     10
4   xxx1  height2      2
5   xxx2  height2      5
6   xxx3  height2      8
7   xxx4  height2     11
8   xxx1  height3      3
9   xxx2  height3      6
10  xxx3  height3      9
11  xxx4  height3     12
```